# How do I use the string array and Dictionary in a method

Tags: c#, class, methods, cycle

I'm trying to create a program that works as a bank account. 4 methods including Deposit, Withdraw, Print and Create. While I was trying to create a switch loop in the `Program.cs` when I got to case "Create": I didn't know how to use the method I created (my switch loop refused to work as well).

I tried switching up from a switch loop to a while to fix the looping issue, and while I got that right I still had no clue how to use the method. I'm working from a lesson which has a supposed answer, but when I tried it, it just doesn't work.

This is how the method looks:

```
private static void Create(string[] cmdArgs, Dictionary<int, BankAccount> accounts)
{
    var id = int.Parse(cmdArgs[1]);

    if (accounts.ContainsKey(id))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Account already exists.");
    }
    else
    {
        var acc = new BankAccount();
        acc.ID = id;
        accounts.Add(id, acc);
    }
}
```

This is how I tried to implement it:

```
string command;

var cmdArgs = command.Split();
var cmdType = cmdArgs[0];

switch (cmdType)
{
    case "Create":
        Create(cmdArgs, accounts);
        break;
}
```

And this is how my lesson shows it (the method is the same in the lesson too)

```
var cmdArgs = command.Split();
var cmdType = cmdArgs[0];

switch (cmdType)
{
    case "Create":
        Create(cmdArgs, accounts);
        break;

    case "Deposit":
        Deposit(cmdArgs, accounts);
        break;

    case "Withdraw":
       break;
}
```

Mine says 'accounts' doesn't exist in this context.

I expected my method to create a bank account with an ID and Balance, but the program can't even start.

Comment: do you have a Dictionary<int, BankAccount> accounts in you r program? any where? if so where if not then add it.

Comment: I do yes, I have a BankAccounts class next to my main Program.cs

Comment: when you say "next to" do you mean inside the scope of the program class? the error you wrote say that you don't have this variable in the scope that you call to the function.

Answer (score 0):

Because "**a**ccounts" and "**A**ccounts" is different string. You should apply lowercasing or uppercasing to cmdArgs[0] and use case with lowercased\uppercase value.

I'll prefer to use [enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/enum) with custom [TypeConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.typeconverter?view=netframework-4.8) for the same tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach has two problems, as far as I can see. First, you never declare your `accounts` variable. As far as your program is concerned, it doesn't exist, hence the error.

The other thing is the fact that you never seem to assign anything to `command`, so even if you added your `accounts`, you'd still get problems because you can't split a string that doesn't exist.

Here's what your code should look like, with both `command` and `accounts` declared and initialised.

```
Dictionary<int, BankAccount> accounts = new Dictionary<int, BankAccount>();

// In reality you'd get this string from elsewhere, like a Console.ReadLine or such
string command = "Create 123";

var cmdArgs = command.Split();
var cmdType = cmdArgs[0];

switch (cmdType)
{
    case "Create":
        Create(cmdArgs, accounts);
        break;
}
```